# Delete Account Signing Groups DocuSign API

Tags: docusignapi

Can I delete Account Signing Groups in DocuSign using API?
If yes, could someone provide me with a sample or direct me to the API that describes this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Documentation for managing signing groups via API can be found [here](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/SigningGroups/).  As that page shows, the HTTP Request for Delete Signing Group(s) is:

DELETE /v2/accounts/{accountId}/signing_groups

For more details about that specific operation, see [here](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/SigningGroups/SigningGroups/delete/).